# Referencing a WP7 border element in tap event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 app that is using bing maps and I have pushpins for multiple locations.  On tapping the pushpin I have a tap event that displays a border with some text.  To hide the text I’m using a tap event for the map control which sets the border visibility to collapsed:

```
private void map_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        this.border.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Now if I am going to be using multiple borders and texts, I’m going to have to set the visibility multiple times like so:

```
this.border.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
this.border2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
this.border3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

So I created a resource for the border in order to refer to just one border.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle" x:Name="border" TargetType="Border" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />      
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And I set the resource in the pushpin

```
<my:Pushpin.Content>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" >
```

But now when I refer to the border in the map_Tap event I get a System.Windows.Style does not contain a definition for ‘Visibility’ because the border is no long referenced as a UIElement(at least that’s how I’m understanding this).  How can a make a style for the border element and still reference it as an element?

Comment: Try removing the x:name attribute of the border style.

Comment: Just tried that..it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you this approach and this might help you for some other tasks too.

You use a `list` of type `border` and add all the `border` elements into it. Now whenever you want to manipulate all the elements you can have a `foreach` loop and access any property you would like example `item.Visibility` and you can manipulate it as you like. This will even help you sort them out so that you can manipulate any specific border.